# ApexChart with React: Pre-select categories

Tags: reactjs, linechart, apexcharts

seeking guidance on ApexChart with React.
I have alot of categories displaying different schedule jobs and total amount of record processed. Is there a way to preselect first 5 records when first load the chart? Below is my issues because i have more than 15 categories.

[image]